# SVN notification when a specific file in the repository changes

Tags: svn

Is there a way to configure SVN to send me email when a specific file in the repository changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably want to write a [post commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1) for your repository.

There are plenty of examples of that if you do a search for it.

Comment: This is technically correct, but I was hoping for something more automagic.  Sorry I took so long to get back to this.